# Where can one find the total size of the eos blockchain?

Tags: blockchains, block-size

Is there a site to see the total size of the eos blockchain like how one can see that the bitcoin blockchain takes 250GB on blockchain.info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the total block size of eos blockchain here:

https://eosnode.tools/blocks

Comment: which software do you use with this download blockchin data? is it cleos or nodoes?